# IndexError in finding the pixel difference of two images

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

This following is code using opencv in python to find the pixel difference of two images of the same size. However, it gives me an error in the last line and I don't know how to fix it.

```
if h1==h2:
    if w1==w2:
        c=np.zeros((h1,w1,3),np.uint8)
        for i in range(img1.shape[0]):
            for j in range(img1.shape[1]):
                c[j][i]=img1[j][i]-img2[j][i]
```

> IndexError: index 480 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 480

Comment: thanks for your valuable replies.. But i tried this methods you suggested.But it returns an error                                                           TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple How can i store the resultant as an array to show it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the indices; `i` belongs to `img1.shape[0]`.

```
img1[j][i]-img2[j][i]
```

That said, numpy can vectorise this process for you and you can simply do

```
if img1.shape == img2.shape:
    c = img1 - img2
```

However, you have to be careful with your data type. What if the pixel in one image is 0 and in the other is 32?

```
>>> np.uint8(0) - np.uint8(32)

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 2
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
224
```

You want to convert them to integers for the difference and if you want to keep the difference in the range 0-255, you can take the absolute of that.

```
c = img1.astype(int) - img2.astype(int)
# you can optionally do the following depending on what you want to do next
c = np.abs(c).astype(np.uint8)
```

OpenCV says a function that achieves all that for you, [cv2.absdiff()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff).

```
c = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
```

Comment: You may want to mention `cv2.absdiff`, since this question is tagged OpenCV

Comment: @Miki Yes, I was just reading about it and experimenting with the package. Thanks for making my life easier.